# What's the best portable way to represent pointer as string in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I need to represent pointers as strings to the user. Sometimes the values might be saved to a file and transferred to a computer with different architecture (32 vs 64 bit is the main issue currently) and loaded from text file to be compared - I'm only going to compare loaded values *with each other*, but I'd still prefer to compare numbers than strings.

I'm currently using:

```
SomeClass* p;
...
printf("%ld", (uintptr_t)p);
```

but I wonder if this is portable (Windows and Linux are only important at this stage though), and whether this would break once 128-bit systems show up?

**Edit**: unless I decide to use uint64_t, and decide that 64bit is the rooftop, this cannot be done because some 64bit pointer might be outside 32bit integer range. So, I decided that it would be safer to compare strings even if it's slower.

Answer (score 20):

For pointers, always use `%p`---it's a format specifier specially designed for printing pointers in the right format. :-)

Comment: But it's not portable. At least, it doesn't given consistent output between platforms. In visual studio, hex values comes out in caps. In gcc, lowercase.

Comment: *shakes head* Is that difference even worth bothering about? You can _never_ have addresses appear the same way across all platforms---e.g., in 16-bit real-mode DOS programs, addresses are usually printed in xxxx:yyyy format. (You can't remove the colon "just to be consistent between platforms"---that would be very misleading, because the address space in real mode DOS programs is not flat.)

Comment: e.g., 0x11110000 and 0x11120000, in flat addressing model, is 0x10000 bytes apart. However, in 16-bit real-mode DOS programs, 1111:0000 and 1112:0000 are 16 bytes apart.

Comment: @Chris: This is the main reason I wrote this question. Using uintptr_t seems to ensure that format of pointer string IS the same across platforms, because it's plain number.

Comment: as you said you wanted this to represent it to the user. i wonder what good is it to represent them nonsensical numbers. why not keep it in a format they understand

Answer (score 10):

I'd do this:

```
std::cout << p;
```

If you have your heart set on cstdio:

```
printf("%p", p);
```

Comment: Thanks Fred. Actually, I'm using wxWidgets which has wxString::Format function that uses snprintf internally so that's why I needed printf example.

Answer (score 7):

printf has a %p formatter which I believe is standardised:

```
printf( "%p", p );
```

but as you are using C++, ostreams already overload pointer output:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;;

class A {};

int main() {
    A a;
    cout << &a << endl;
}
```

produces:

```
0x22ff6f
```

Comment: Be carefull though. As they also specialise the output operator for char* and print a C-String.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the `%p` formatting string?

```
printf("%p", p);
```

This'll give the hex-encoded address the pointer points to (and, I think, formats `NULL`s for you as well).

Answer (score 0):

I would have done:

```
cout << p << endl;
```

Strings (of the same encoding) are portable.  If you want to compare them as pointers, you have to parse the string back into an `unsigned long` first.

As for 128-bit systems, they're a ways off.  WIth 64 bits, you can directly address 16.8 million terabytes of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done as

printf("%#x", p);

This would ensure similar format (0x...) across platforms.